# merging two matrices by rownumber and entry number

Tags: r

I am having matrix A which looks like:

```
 [1,]StreetName,,
 [2,]ZipCode,Rooms,Size
 [3,]Type,Details,Condition
 [4,]StreetName,,
 [5,]ZipCode,Rooms,Size
 [6,]Type,Details,Condition
```

As you might notice, there is a repeat for every third Row. 1,3 etc. 
I have made a matrix B that looks like this.

```
 [1,]     1      2     3
 [2,]     4      5     6
```

(Made it by seq())

So my question is.. Is there any possible way of merging the rownumbers of the first one to match with the numbers of entry in the matrix B

Finally i'd like to end up with a result like this:

```
[1,]StreetName ZipCode Rooms Size Type Details Condition
[1,]StreetName ZipCode Rooms Size Type Details Condition
```

To be more explicit, i am merging every 2/3 and 3/3 row to be at the end of 1/3 row. Like this: 
1/3 2/3 3/3

[Edit] - I do not know how to make a connection between the Rows of Matrix A so that they fit into the adequate entry-numbers in matrix B. Does anyone have a suggestion, a comment or maybe a referral of how to do this?

Comment: I smell [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do?

Comment: I see. I will edit

Comment: Your matrix `A` looks like a vector. Perhaps you want `matrix(as.vector(A), ncol = 3, byrow = T)`?

Comment: Dear Gregor. Matrix A is a matrix of i6,j3. I've edited the text to commaformatted so that it stands more clear.

Comment: Pleas use `dput()` to share A as the structure is still not clear. `dput(A)` or `dput(head(A))` would be perfect.

Comment: are you trying to concatenate the strings from every 3 rows in A?